# Cannot assign a value of type 'int' to a value of type 'String?'

Tags: ios, xcode6, swift2

Here is my code, I am a beginner using swift and my code does not work, the application should take the value of 'ageInput' textField and multiply it by 7 then show the results inside resultLabel, I always get the error:

Cannot assign a value of type 'int' to a value of type 'String?'

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageInput: UITextField!
    @IBAction func findAge(sender: AnyObject) {

        var catAge = ageInput.text.toInt() ?? 0

        catAge = catAge * 7 ?? 0

        resultLabel.text = catAge

    }
       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

Where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try:

```
resultLabel.text = String (catAge)
```

Comment: Comment: It fixed the error in the code but when i click on the button, the label still as its and did not changed.

Comment: I checked your code, and it should work well. Please check all outlets connections. Try to set breakpoint, and see findAge execution process and variable values

Answer (score 17):

You can also do:

```
resultLabel.text = "\(catAge)"
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Works perfectly with 3.0

Answer (score 2):

here i have tray to solve your problem using example and i hope your issue will solved..

```
var stringNumber = "1234"
var numberFromString = stringNumber.toInt()
println(numberFromString)
```

Note toInt():

```
If the string represents an integer that fits into an Int, returns the  corresponding integer.
```